# Alter query data according to user type

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

This is my model and view. I have 3 types of users who get fixed discounts of 30% + 5%, 30% + 10% and 20 % + 5% respectively on every product. Is there a way for me to do it without hard coding the price for each user in the models

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Ancillary(models.Model):
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
    standard = models.CharField(max_length=120,   null=True)
    measurement = models.CharField(max_length=120,  null=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=120,   null=True)
    price = models.Int(max_length=120,   null=True)

 class Meta:
      verbose_name_plural = "Ancillaries"
 def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('ancillaries')
 def __unicode__(self):
      return u'%s %s %s %s %s %s  %s' % (self.id, self.product_code, self.type, 
                            self.product, self.standard, 
                            self.measurement, self.brand)


class AncillaryDetail(DetailView):
    model = Ancillary
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(AncillaryDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Ancillary_list'] = Ancillary.objects.all()
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a method to `Ancillary` that returns the discounted price for a given user. You can then call it from your view, passing in the logged-in `User`.

```
class Ancillary(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_discounted_price(self, user):
        # check type of user and return discounted price
```

You haven't said how you're defining these different types of user. The most general solution would be to customize your `User` object (or use a `User` profile) to point to its type, where the type is another model that gives its associated discount. Then you could control the types and the discount amount from the admin without hardcoding anything.

Comment: @wdect: That depends on whether a user can have multiple types or not. From what you've said I assume not, in which case it would just be a `ForeignKey`.